# Echarts markLine doesn't appear. (Bar Chart)

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

im trying to create two markLines with my averages (yearly and last 13 weeks) the first markline will be my yearly average with a small tooltip position around January. My second one will be my last 13 weeks averages with a small position at around july. The screenshot below is what I have.

[image]

Here is a screenshot the small tooltip. Has to be a markline too.

[image]

Here are my options. MarkLine doesn't appear at all.

```js
     xAxis: [
        {
          type: "category",
          data: Object.keys(resultObject),
          show: false,
        },
        {
          position: "bottom",
          type: "category",
          data: categories.map((category) => category.charAt(0)),
          xAxisIndex: 2,
          show: true,
          axisLine: {
            show: false,
          },
          axisTick: {
            show: false,
          },
        },
      ],
      yAxis: {
        show: false,
        type: "value",
      },
      series: [
        {
          data: Object.values(resultObject),
          type: "bar",
          itemStyle: {
            color: (seriesIndex) =>
              seriesIndex.dataIndex > 39 ? "#FF5630" : "#A19D9A",
          },
          markLine: {
            data: {
              name: "Horizontal line with Y value at 100",
              yAxis: 100,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error. The [`data` property](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.markLine.data) is a **list** of `markLine` objects, which are specified by either

- A) a value at an axis (eg. `yAxis: 200` or `type: 'average'`) or
- B) a list of two points (eg. `coord: [10,20]` or `type: 'min'`)

```js
markLine: {
    data: [
        // case A
        {yAxis: 200},        // example 1
        {type: 'average'},   // example 2

        // case B
        [
            {coord: [10, 20]},    // example 1
            {coord: [50, 300]}
        ],

        [
            {type: 'min'},        // example 2
            {type: 'max'}
        ],

        [
            {coord: [10, 20]},    // example 3
            {type: 'max'}
        ]
    ]
}
```

Here is a small [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoW6AeBBDEDOAXMmuqemAJ4gCmRARAMYCGY1A5sAE4V0A0JZdABMWTIgG0A5IE6HSb1iTA34pyFgR_MVkwAraGwGhGGwKABGwCRyGwODGGwBTqGwGeRGwPI6GwFByGwIt2GwBVKGwL8BGwPiaGwCvAjw1ASn8NQD5TORkNZXlJdTjtOL04wziTOPM4qzjbOIc45wBdfkFYAF9SwQocfCJUMvIqWlg6ADcmABsAV2o-AUE8AAtgAHciADMuvGoB9Eq52BnOCGpCWHFF9AbG4VEJACYDgAZ5AEYADgPzgE4z-QOAZgAWB5vT2EfHj8ezj7OnvJns9rp8DvdYO9zs8bg8_ucjucvvIvq9YGcbhcEY8EQBWB4nIEglHg-RQ9EwuH_RHo5GfF63LHowHM_GwI7HEpbUiUGj0ABGTE4_V26AgrAAtgBlSidFo7UWwBjATpcIgACmWqzwAEloEJqBgAJQIAB83LKWrWeoNGAAdCIwEwbYbYKb2QA2WAAflaAGIAGIB3Ee750WD0P1YDEAERuWBFooWiolQoA1gAZCDQeUW0iOsQbPNlAD0JaVTBmsCwxcECsV1Vq62ex2OtbIyYbZHrXaafIUTDa1E4TDY1EksHbpE7vcns_QZYrVYAQlP0Jt56Qe_PlVwhBJJFlYC2imvp1VN9vZ7vOPuNpIgijW6fN_Mz1zNxvX1fe7yWpIJWzSQz3mC95x_Ls_yIACmAwYDXwqd8pxfJNuRnUguXKABuIA).

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering tried the examples, and still nothing.

Comment: There are no markLines in the example link I provided?

Comment: There are. Tried to implement them in my application but still nothing. Maybe is a problem because I'm using react-native-charts for mobile applications. (which uses  apache echarts)

Comment: Yes, it does not seem to be an echarts issue. If you would provide a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) implementation I could have a look at it. Just note, that I have never used react.

Comment: If you are adding it on click, try adding markLine: {}, in the initial option. Then in the click function add the detail of where it should appear and styling